# Retrieving uniq records with union in mysql

Tags: mysql, duplicates, union

I have two tables usersin and usersout(I can not change schema, a lot of system changes must be done in php otherwise). I should get all user records in a query but I should mark them if they are in or out also a user may have an in record and out record I shouldn't show in record if has an out record.

I have created tables with sample data in SQL Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ac99a/1/0

Can u help me how can I remove duplicates of user records in this union query?

Comment: is the fiddle working for you? gives me internal error all the time..

Comment: it is working, I also checked with different browser

Comment: so you want to see all entries with either in our out entries, but not the ones with both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have all entries with an entry in either the in or out table, but not in both of them, then a full outer join would be your friend.

Since MySQL does not know that kind of join, you can emulate it with a left outer join and a right outer join combined like so:

```
SELECT 
  ui.id, ui.user, 'i' 
FROM 
  usersIN ui 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
  usersOUT uo ON ui.user = uo.user 
WHERE uo.id IS NULL 
UNION 
SELECT 
  uo.id, uo.user, 'o' 
FROM 
  usersIN ui 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
  usersOUT uo ON ui.user = uo.user 
WHERE ui.id IS NULL;
```

This should give you the right output.

A good visual explanation of joins can be [found here](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

Comment: Thank you, I just wanted ((A-B) U B)  I changed second part of your snippet an use it, thank you.